# Reading subset / subarea of GeoTIFF file without having to read whole file first?

Tags: python, tiff, geotiff, satellite-image

I have more than 10k of tiff-landsat images, though I only need to read a predefined pixel area by given coordinates. Is there a solution to handle thsi fast and easy, without reading the whole tiff?

I thought there might be a solution that I am able to read the predefined area and not the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

found the solution: windows from rasterio does the job https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html

Comment: You might add a code example as the pure link might not be available in the future.